# Construct Completely Ad-hoc Slick Query

Tags: slick, scala-2.10

Pardon my newbieness but im trying to build a completely ad-hoc query builder using slick.  From our API, I will get a list of strings that is representative of the table, as well as another list that represents the filter for the tables, munge then together to create a query.  The hope is that I can take these and create the inner join.  A similar example of what i'm trying to do would be JIRA's advanced query builder.

I've been trying to build it using reflection but I've come across so many blocking issues i'm wondering if this is even possible at all.

In code this is what I want to do:

```
def getTableQueryFor(tbl:String):TableQuery[_] = {
   ... a matcher that returns a tableQueries?
   ... i think the return type is incorrect b/c erasure?
}


def getJoinConditionFor:(tbl1:String, tbl2:String) => scala.slick.lifted.Column[Boolean] = (l:Coffees,r:Suppies) => {
    ...a matcher
}
```

Is the Following even possible?

```
val q1 = getTableQueryFor("coffee")
val q2 = getTableQueryFor("supply")
val q3 = q1.innerJoin.q2.on(getJoinCondition("coffee", "supply")
```

*edit: Fixed grammar issue.*